# ImportXML and ImportJSON doesn't work. How to import data from dynamic website?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the website: https://www.homesnap.com/CA/Sun-Valley/11027-Cohasset-Street

[image: IMAGE LINK]

I want the value `$543,000` to be scraped into one cell.

ImportXML parsed "imported content is empty". Here is the formula

```
=ImportXML("https://www.homesnap.com/CA/Sun-Valley/11027-Cohasset-Street","//div[@class='property-header-price']")
```

and ImportJSON return

> "syntax error: unexpexted token".

```
=ImportJSON("https://www.homesnap.com/CA/Sun-Valley/11027-Cohasset-Street","/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div")
```

Any advice to import the data?

Answer (score 2):

you need some other source. Google Sheets does not support the scraping of JavaScript elements. you can test JS dependency simply by disabling JS for a given site and what's left can be scraped. in your case its nothing:

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you player0 for the feedback. fyi, i use Importdata for the url and there are some info appear to be scrape. for example if i use this formula : =index(IMPORTDATA("https://www.homesnap.com/CA/Sun-Valley/11027-Cohasset-Street"),32,1) will give me (<meta property="og:price" content="543000" /> . but the result can vary in other different sheet.